# Replace strings on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to replace strings on wordpress e.g instead if **username**, it should be **login name**

i.e. **username** = **login name**

any help would be deeply appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I would like it to be effective in all WP content

Comment: Where would you like to replace text, in specific page, form, or in all WP content, posts? Please try to be more accurate and to show us some code.

Comment: I would like it to be effective in all WP content.

Comment: Where are you trying to replace the text though? Are you trying to make a replacement in the database with SQL or are you just trying to echo out replaced text with PHP in a template file? What have you tried to do that hasn't worked?

Comment: Just use some of existing plugins, as [Real time find and replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/real-time-find-and-replace/)

Comment: Thanks @skobaljic that worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @skobaljic

I Just use some of existing plugins, as [Real time find and replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/real-time-find-and-replace/)
If you dont see any changes be sure to turn off Cache if you have any installed on your wordpress site. Enjoy!